# All of the sudden getting too many error "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" on opening .ts source files

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am working on an angular 2 application in VSCODE.

Everything was working perfect, until yesterday when I started getting "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" upon opening any .ts files.

[image]

That is, I have to click on the close button of the error every time.

Everything works fine, I just have to keep closing the error pops. Vey annoying and impacts my productivity.

How can eliminate this redundant error?

Comment: Install webstorm :-)

Comment: Is it coming from an extension? Try `--disable-extensions`. Are there any more error details if you open Developer Tools? Open a github issue with these details.

Comment: Allan, Can you please navigate to **Help** menu => **Toggle Developer Tools** and then to **Console** in the devloper tools (being displayed) and post the error message here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for help.

I built up on good suggestions here and this steps solved the problem:

1- Disable all Angular and TS related extensions.

2- Restart VCCODE

1- Re-enable extensions you disabled in the step 1.

3- Restart VCCODE

When you open the work space, TSLint might need some time to re-calculate and re-reload the symbols. After that everything is back to normal.

If the problem strikes back again, I will un-mark this answer.